# Google Cloud audit service account usage

Tags: google-cloud-platform, service-accounts

I have some old service accounts on a Google Cloud project. I want to find out if they are still being used or that I can safely delete them. Is there a way to see when they were last used? And maybe how often?

I guess I could just delete the key and hope nothing breaks, but that seems a bit iffy. Is there a better solution?

Answer (score 4):

At this time, there is no tool within the Google cloud platform to list where exactly Service account keys are used, or when last they were used or how often they are used. However, with the [GCloud command line](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/iam/service-accounts/keys/list), you can list all Service Account keys (within your project) with the Creation Date(which is often the date of creation of the Service Account - For Default Keys) and the Expiry Date for the Key.

$ gcloud iam service-accounts keys list --iam-account [IAM_account] --project [projectName]

You can verify if Keys of your old [User-managed Service account](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/service-accounts#user-managed_service_accounts) are not expired yet - Hence, they are probably still being used.

If you delete the service accounts that are still used by running instances, the instances may start failing their operations. However, you can contact the [Google Cloud platform team](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/) to help with re-adding the deleted Service account back to your project.

Answer (score 1):

Check https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/audit/

```
gcloud logging read "logName=(projects/[PROJECT_ID]/logs/cloudaudit.googleapis.com%2Factivity
  OR projects/[PROJECT_ID]/logs/cloudaudit.googleapis.com%2Fsystem_events
  OR projects/[PROJECT_ID]/logs/cloudaudit.googleapis.com%2Fdata_access)
```

or online https://console.cloud.google.com/home/activity

`gcloud` return YAML with IP addresses! I see SQL connection activities.

Answer (score 1):

I follow a 2-step process to delete or disable service accounts in a gcp project:

1. List unused service accounts

```sh
gcloud recommender insights list \
    --insight-type=google.iam.serviceAccount.Insight \
    --location=global \
    --filter=insightSubtype=SERVICE_ACCOUNT_USAGE \
    --project <PROJECT_ID> --format=json | jq -r '.[]|select(.content.lastAuthenticatedTime == null)|.content.email, .lastRefreshTime' | paste -d, - - | sort -t, -k1 -k2 > /tmp/unused-sa.csv
```

2. Disable (or delete) the unused accounts

```sh
cat /tmp/unused-sa.csv | cut -d, -f1 | while read line; do
    echo "$line"
    gcloud --project <PROJECT_ID> iam service-accounts disable "$line"
done
```